# Efficient change detection/watcher in tree data structure

Tags: javascript, performance, data-structures, tree, treeview

I have a library page which is hierarchical data. I using tree data structure for this. Data is stored in mysql db.

I am trying to integrate red dot notification on all parents whose child has been updated or added.(This will help user to know which content is being updated)

One way to do that is save the snapshot of previous tree state and compare it with current tree state using brute force way.

The structure of library table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `library` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,    //name of entity
  `description` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,   //description
  `image_url` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,     // image if any
  `is_first` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  // use to check root
  `is_last` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   // use to check if it is last level  
  `is_admin_created` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  // use to check if it is created by admin or not.
  `parent` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,  //parent id ,if it is root then null
  `resource_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, // type of resource
  `resource_description` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,  // resource description
  `resource_path` varchar(10000) DEFAULT NULL,  // resource path (url or sql query to get data)
  `student_class` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  // class wise trees
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `student_id` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,  // if it is not created by admin then student id
  `is_active` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',  // use to check if it is active or not
  `is_delete` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',  
  `master_parent` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,  // root parent id
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I can only add column in this table , can't change major structure.

Comment: How exactly are you storing the tree? Can you show any code?

Comment: @Nisarg  I have updated the question with table structure.